# Live shaping of GridView in UWP - refresh groups when items change

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

In WPF I've used ICollectionViewLiveShaping to reflect changed in underlying collection to the itemscontrols in UI:

```
var collectionView = new ListCollectionView(myCollection);
collectionView.GroupDescription.Add(new GroupDescription("HasData"));
var liveShaping = (ICollectionViewLiveShaping)collectionView;
liveShaping.LiveGroupingProperties.Add("HasData");
liveShaping.IsLiveGrouping = true;
```

when I did this, the grouping in the UI was automatically refreshed:

```
void SetData(int index)
{
   var item = myCollection[index];
   item.HasData = true;
}
```

How to achieve it in the UWP?

Comment: How to achieve it in UI or how to achieve it in UWP app?

Comment: In UWP, sorry. Fixed.